# How to set variables in python script and change them each time script run?

Tags: python

For example:

code1

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def fetch():
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

    time.sleep(2)

    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")
    button.send_keys("text1")

if __name__=="__main__":
    fetch()

time.sleep(3)

driver.close()
```

code2

```
from code1 import fetch

for i in range(3):
    fetch()
```

How to set variables to change send keys in google search bar each time loop is run in range(3) text1, text2, text3 ?

Comment: FYI Google will quickly notice what you're doing and show a captcha to anyone with the same IP address. Scraping Google is a pain in the ass. It took me a month to figure out that they were looking for js variables injected by chromedriver

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Instead of asking a question about variables, tell us what the end goal is.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over a numeric range, iterate over the list of keys you want to use, and pass each key as an argument to `fetch`.

In order to do that, you need to change the `fetch` function in code1 to take one argument and pass it to `button.send_keys`:

```
def fetch(key):
    # ...
    button.send_keys(key)
```

Then use it like this in code2:

```
for key in ["text1", "text2", "text3"]:
    fetch(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may no have understood entirely, is this what you mean?

```
def fetch(no):
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

    time.sleep(2)

    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")
    button.send_keys("text{}".format(no))
    driver.close()
```

```
from code1 import fetch

for i in range(3):
    fetch(i)
```